# ZK: Force server to send updated value to peer widget

Tags: client-server, zk

I have a current setup where client updates a combobox value at client only (not updating the component at server).The server updates both widget and component when setValue() is done.
However it does not when the existing value is the same as the one being set.

Consider the following:-

```
1.client-setValue('1') - values{client:'1',server:""} 
2.server-setValue("2") - values{client:'2',server:"2"}
3.client-setValue('') - values{client:'',server:"2"}  
4.server-setValue('2') - values{client:'',server:"2"}--server does not update client as the value at server is the same as the one being set.

**Forcefully updating client:-**

1.client-setValue('1') - values{client:'1',server:""} 
2.server-setValue("2") and forcefully updateclient - values{client:'2',server:"2"}
3.client-setValue('') - values{client:'',server:"2"}  
4.server-setValue('2') and forcefully update client- values{client:'2',server:"2"}
```

Is this anyhow possible, other than setting one garbage/irrelevant value before setting the actual value ,which would possibly have the garbage value as the latest value and will update the client.

**EDIT:**
[ZK Fiddle link](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2jjucb5/4-Zk-Server-smartupdate-in-case-of-same-value)

Comment: can you please post some code or create a fiddle?

Comment: @chillworld please see the edit.

Comment: @chillworld 1.set the value just on client by pressing 2 and then  2. set value from server as xx('older one')-server does not send update to client.But if i do 2.set value from server as foo('totally new')-server does update the client this time.

Comment: Don't you need to send a `zAu.send(new zk.Event(zk.Widget.$('checker'), 'onChange', jq('$checker').val()));`?

Comment: @chillworld to reduce the client server traffic i am only updating it on the client ,(this is the point of all this) and eventually sending it (Widget.smartupdate('value','val')) when submit button is clicked.

Comment: why so complicated? use mvvm and do `@load(vm.item) @save(vm.item, before='someCommand');  Then it will only go to server before your command is triggered

Comment: @chillworld The code i had referred was just an example of what is happening ,actual issue is far more complicated,i have multiple button clicking upon which i do a calculation and update a combobox for the same,calculation being big i decided to do it on the client side but the combobx is used by other methods too and there needs to be some way to reduce the traffic between client server and only update at client and only send back when submit button is pressed.Hope i am making myself clear.

Comment: it's always more difficult but without your complex example it's hard to help

Comment: @chillworld OK,letme see if i can mimic the same. BTW i managed to get over it with a workaround that is setting some random value before setting the actual value.